# HTML scraping with hpricot using Ruby 1.8.7 vs 1.9.2

Tags: ruby

Relevant snippet from test.html:

```
<div id="seat_31F_vacant" class="seatVacant" onclick="UpdateHost(this);Common.DoPostBack('lbtPostBack','31F');" onmouseover="Seat_onMouseOver(this)" onmouseout="Seat_onMouseOut(this)">F</div>
```

Now consider this ruby code:

```
doc = Hpricot(test.html)
  
doc.search("//div[@class='seats']").each do |seat|          
    @vacant_seat += seat.to_s.scan(/id="seat_(.*)_vacant/)
end

@log.info @vacant_seat.to_s
```

When logging @vacant_seat.to_s this is what I end up with:

> [["31F"], ["31E"], ["31D"], ["31C"]] (Using **1.9.2**)
>
> 31F31E31D31C (Using **1.8.7**)

that means if I do @vacant_seat[0].to_s I'll get:

> **["31F"]** (**1.9.2**) and **31F** (**1.8.7**)

I want to end up with 31F (as I do with 1.8.7)

Any thougts? Is there a generic way to do this that will work in both Ruby versions? I need to extract the string (eg. 31F) which is located between the underscore characters (_) in the ID attributes. If there is a better way to do this I would appreciate to hear about it.

Comment: How is this related to cucumber or watir?

Comment: It would be easier to reproduce the problem if you provide relevant HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I want to use this later on to automate a few tests (using watir-webdriver and clicking on the collected elements during a test run) and thought maybe this was a common problem for people doing that (scraping htmls). I can also see how it's more of a Ruby thing though, so if you think the tags are misleading I can remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.2 changed to_s for Arrays. It used to concatenate all of the elements and print them like `31F31E31D31C`.

Now it adds fancy formatting to make it look like an array, so you see the brackets on the arrays, and quotes to the string elements inside of them, so you get `[["31F"], ["31E"], ["31D"], ["31C"]]`.

It looks like `@vacant_seat` is an array of arrays, so that's why `@vacant_seat[0].to_s` gives you `["31F"]`.

If you just need the array that has the elements, then it's the same array in both, just being printed differently.

Now, you can use `join` to call what was to_s in 1.8.7. `@vacant_seat.join #=> 31F31E31D31C` or `@vacant_seat[0].join #=> 31F`, will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could the same code be an array of arrays for 1.9.2? I think arrays are handled the same way for both version. You seem to have a point on the formatting thing though.. the to_s method for an Array will print them out whith brackets and quotes etc...